# Sorting Before Event in jQuery jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am working on jQuery's jqGrid and I am not using paging in my jqGrid. My code fetch more than 1000 rows data and all data shows in jqGrid without paging and use `loadonce: true` property. Now my requirement is that when user sort any column it takes 3-5 seconds to sorting  data so i want to show at that time loading image. I wrote

```
beforeRequest: function () { jQuery(".imgLoading").show(0);}, 
gridComplete: function () {jQuery(".imgLoading").hide(0);}
```

these 2 events and it works fine when data comes with server and manipulating with server.

But I want to sorting on client side by using `loadonce: true` and want to show loading image also but I don't know on which event I will write down image show hide code.

Please tell me the name of `BeforeSortEvent` and `AfterSortEvent` of jqGrid.

I checked on this URL : http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events but didn't find right event.

Please help me out.....

Comment: during the 3-5 seconds needed mostly for filling of 1000 rows (mostly non-visible rows) web browser is full busy. I'm afraid, it *can't* show anything. Why you want that web browser do unneeded work? Why you want to fill page with 1000 rows if the user can see only about 50 rows? Why you don't want to use *local* paging of data? In the case you will be able to display practically immediately for example 10000 rows instead of 1000.

Comment: @Oleg I think Oleg means that with paging you will immediately see the smaller subset of the sorted rows if you use paging, Ex 50 vs 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
onSortCol: function(index, iCol, sortorder) {
    jQuery(".imgLoading").show(0);
},
gridComplete: function() { 
    jQuery(".imgLoading").hide(0);
}
```

**EDIT**

Since you said the `alert()` fires off, I'm thinking your problem is in the way you are showing/hiding those `.imgLoading` elements.

Try:

```
onSortCol: function(index, iCol, sortorder) {
    alert("I'm about to SHOW the loading message");
    $(".imgLoading").show();
},
gridComplete: function() { 
    alert("I'm about to HIDE the loading message");        
    $(".imgLoading").hide();
}
```

Be sure those two `alert()`'s fire off, and if they do, then something is still off with those `.imgLoading` elements you are trying to show/hide.

Comment: @GauravAgrawal when you click to sort a column, does the loader message show at all? If you put an `alert("Test")` in there, does that fire off when you click on a column heading to sort?

Comment: When I am using alert message it works but if I removed alert message from the code its not working.

Comment: @GauravAgrawal ok, so something is wrong with how you are showing/hiding the `.imgLoading` element. See my EDITS in my answer...